# NetSuite what factors decide which script is referenced from the file cabinet?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

Let's say I have two NetSuite instances. NS0 and NS1.

NS0 has been around for a while. It has scripts installed, custom records, etc.

NS1 is a brand new instance.

I deploy scripts from a version controlled SDF project to NS1 and then also deploy a bundle (maybe from NS0) that contains (possibly outdated) scripts... what decides which script is referenced from the file cabinet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see/change, which script file from the file cabinet is referenced, on the `script record`.

In your case, look at the projects and see which one is active. From there you can find the script record and then the script file associated with it.